# Aurelia page life cycle - order of execution in routing/rendering pipeline

Tags: aurelia

What is the order of execution in Aurelia routing and rendering pipeline when application navigates from one URL to another?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two lifecycles:

Router Lifecycle is:

1. Previous Screen `canDeactivate`
2. Next Screen is instantiated
3. Next Screen `canActivate`
4. Previous Screen `deactivate`
5. Next Screen `activate`
6. Next Screen is rendered.

The Component Lifecycle is:

When loaded:

1. `created`
2. `bind`
3. `attached`

When unloaded:

1. `detached`
2. `unbind`

As to how this all goes together, simply adding each of these callbacks to two routed pages and logging the calls shows this:

```
Previous Page canDeactivate
Next Page canActivate
Previous Page deactivate
Next Page activate
Next Page created
Next Page bind
Previous Page detached
Previous Page unbind
Next Page attached
```

If we include the router hooks (steps) that were included in your original answer, then it looks like this:

```
Previous Page canDeactivate
Authorize step
Next Page canActivate
Pre-activate step
Previous Page deactivate
Next Page activate
Pre-render step
Next Page created
Next Page bind
Post-render step
Previous Page detached
Previous Page unbind
Next Page attached
```

I've included both as most applications won't have the hooks added.

Answer (score 0):

Taken thet Aurelia application navigates from `Route1` containing `View1`, which is already loaded, to `Route2` containing `View2`:

> 1. View1 - canDeactivate
> 2. Route2 - autorizeStep
> 3. View2 - canActivate
> 4. Route2 - preActivate
> 5. View1 - deactivate
> 6. View2- activate
> 7. Route2 - preRenderStep
> 8. Route2 - postRenderStep
> 9. View1 - detached
> 10. View2- attached